# Using IVSHMEM with libvirt virt-manager

Tags: shared-memory, virtualization, qemu, libvirt, apparmor

Using **ivshmem** in **qemu** requires the following steps.

1. Start ivshmem server in host `./ivshmem_server` which will create a unix domain socket `/tmp/ivshmem_socket`
2. Start qemu with the following command line options- `-chardev socket,path=/tmp/ivshmem_socket,id=ivshmem_socket -device ivshmem,chardev=ivshmem_socket,size=1m`

Now if we do `lspci` in guest, the ivshmem pci device is shown in it.

How can I do the same in virt-manager?
Specifically, I want to do 2 things.

- Pass the above command line option to qemu, when virt-manager starts it
- libvirt virt-manager uses **apparmor** to isolate guests, how to make sure that access to `/tmp/ivshmem_socket` is not denied to the VM ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Passing command line options**

Passing command line option to qemu from virt-manager requires the following steps.

- `virsh edit <name of vm>` , or directly modify the file using `vim /etc/libvirt/qemu/<name of virtual machine>.xml`
- change `<domain type='kvm'>` to `<domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>`
- add tags for command line parameters

> ```
> <qemu:commandline>
>     <qemu:arg value='-chardev'/>
>     <qemu:arg value='socket,path=/tmp/ivshmem_socket,id=ivshmem_socket'/>
>     <qemu:arg value='-device'/>
>     <qemu:arg value='ivshmem,chardev=ivshmem_socket,size=1m'/>
> </qemu:commandline>
> ```

After doing this, qemu will try to access `/tmp/ivshmem_socket`, and because of apparmor (libvirt was using apparmor in my case, it may as well use SeLinux), the access will be denied, and an error similar to the following will be shown.

```
error starting domain: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor:
  ...
virt-manager Failed to connect socket: Permission denied
```

**AppArmor**

To fix this error, the following two steps are required.

***1. Make qemu run as root*** (This step is `optional`, and may not be required for you, continue to second step)

- vim `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`
- change the lines `user =`, and `group =` , to the following

> user = "root" 
>   group = "root"

Restart PC or libvirt daemon.

***2. AppArmor***

- find the uuid of guest from its xml configuration file (use virsh edit  and look for  tag)
- cd `/etc/apparmor.d/libvirt`
- check if `libvirt-<uuid>` file is present, replace `<uuid>` with uuid of vm
- Change AppArmor mode to complain, instead of enforcing, which will allow all actions of the VM, and log those which should have been blocked.

  `sudo aa-complain libvirt-<uuid> //replace <uuid> with uuid of vm`