# libvirt Apparmor permission denied when accessing qemu socket

Tags: virtual-machine, libvirt, apparmor, virsh

I was trying to use ivshmem device of qemu, after running the server, I can succesfully create a vm with command:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -hda testvm01.img -enable-kvm \
-device ivshmem-doorbell,vectors=1,chardev=ivshmem \
-chardev socket,path=/tmp/ivshmem_socket,id=ivshmem
```

Then I want to use libvirt to boot the vm, and my configuration file as follows:

```
<domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
  <name>testlinux1</name>
  <memory unit='KiB'>1048576</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>1048576</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-bionic'>hvm</type>
  </os>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/gavin/vms/testvm01.img'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
  </devices>
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-device'/>
    <qemu:arg value='ivshmem-doorbell,vectors=2,chardev=ivshmem'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-chardev'/>
    <qemu:arg value='socket,path=/tmp/ivshmem_socket,id=ivshmem'/>
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>
```

When I try to create the vm with command `virsh create testlinux1.xml`, I get the error:

```
error: Failed to start domain testlinux1
error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2018-07-19T22:12:52.443682Z qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev socket,path=/tmp/ivshmem_socket,id=ivshmem: Failed to connect socket /tmp/ivshmem_socket: Permission denied
```

I have seen the same question at: [Using IVSHMEM with libvirt virt-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799366/using-ivshmem-with-libvirt-virt-manager)

I can not follow the solution there since I failed to create the vm, there is no  `libvirt-<uuid>` file under `/etc/apparmor.d/libvirt`, and I have no way to change AppArmor mode to complain with `sudo aa-complain libvirt-<uuid> //replace <uuid> with uuid of vm`.

Can anyone helps me figure out how to change the mode to complain before creating the file? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can put AppArmor in complain mode for libvirt:

```
aa-complain /usr/sbin/libvirtd
```

This disables the security, so may not be the best solution.

Comment: That worked for me. But, does such practice incur a security risk?

Comment: Yes, the security will be lower, as AppArmor will only complain about policy violations instead of enforcing the policy for `libvirtd`.